# How to display (converted) Word document content in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, viewer, documents

There is Page Viewer Web Part which can display HTML page. Is there another webpart that can display the content of the Word document or alternatively a way to convert a Document from inside OOTB Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

MOSS Enterprise can display office documents in the browser. If that's not what you are using you will need either a third party product (not aware of any that do exactly what you are after) or custom code and a third party library that can load word documents.

You could also try just using the page viewer web part - that will be very much browser dependent, but may be ok in an intranet environment.

Comment: so displaying Word Docs inline is not available on a standard (non-enterprise) Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically [convert the file to pdf](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint.aspx) inside SharePoint and display that using the Page Viewer web part.